# Determinant formula manipulation

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, determinant

Let $P\in M_{k\times n}$ and $A\in M_{n\times k}$ then
$$det(PA)=\sum_{\sigma\in S_k}\text{sgn}(\sigma)\prod_i (PA)_{i,\sigma(i)}$$
$$=\sum_{\sigma\in S_k}\text{sgn}(\sigma)\prod_i \sum_jP_{ij}A_{j,\sigma(i)}$$
$$\overset{(*)}{=}\sum_{j_1,...,j_k}P_{1,j_1}\cdots P_{k,j_k}(\sum_\sigma \text{sgn}(\sigma)\cdot A_{j_1,\sigma(1)}\cdots A_{j_k,\sigma(k)})$$

I don't understand the last transition $(*)$, this was taken as part of some proof in ring theory. $j_1,\dots,j_n$ weren't defined before $(*)$ so you just kind of need to figure out what are they. Can someone help me understand that transition? Thanks.

Comment: The author simply expands the product of sums $\prod_{i}\sum_j$ and writes it in a more "explicit" way. It's the same as writing $(x_{1,1}+x_{1,2}+x_{1,3})(x_{2,1}+x_{2,2}+x_{2,3})=\sum_{i,j}x_{1,i}x_{2,j}$.

Comment: @Yourong'DZR'Zang Thanks! I just got it right now, just to clarify, in the product I have k sums, then from each sum I 'pick' some $P_{ij}$ which is followed by $A_{ij}$  then in total I get sum that is detmired by all the possible ways to pick $k$ elements from $n$

Comment: You got the idea.